# Getting span html in each function - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am having lot of span tags with same class. how to get the html of them in each function angular. Please help. Thanks in advance!. For eg :

```
<span class="amount">500</span>
<span class="amount">1000</span>
```

how to retrieve 500,1000 .... etc.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It's very unclear what you mean by retrieve 500.  I actually see nothing angular related in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly , custom `directive` can be used with isolate scope (which acts a reusable component) in your span tags to get the amount. please refer the code below

In the below code I have used the $scope array variable (2 way binded) and passed it to the directive which gets updated the amount . I have use $timeout only to showcase the results in your controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.amountArray = [];

  $timeout(function(){
    console.log('from controller',$scope.amountArray);
  },2000);

});

app.directive('getAmounts',function(){
   return{
     restirct:'A',
     scope:{
       amountsContent:'=amountArray'

     },
     link:function(scope,element,attrs){

       var amountValue = element.html();
       scope.amountsContent.push(amountValue);
       console.log(scope.amountsContent);

     }
   }
});
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ACGsmPX3HWcuRYLe6ut?p=preview)

Comment: Thank You. Your understanding is correct. but i tried doing this in each function and I din use timeout to get the value of span.

Comment: @SethuRaja I just added the $timeout inorder to show its getting two data binded and amount values are updated ! . however i'm glad it worked for you :)